# Setting up RoleManagement on ASP.NET Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity

I have a Web-application in Azure looking at an azure sql database, in which I have used Migrations to create my database AND the ASP.NET Identity tables. I have enabled it in my web.config thus:

```
  <roleManager
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      defaultProvider="OurSqlRoleProvider"
     >
      <providers>
          <add
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             applicationName="/"
             name="OurSqlRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>

  </roleManager>
```

Which when I try to look at any role in the web application gives me this error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

What have I done wrong?

**edit**
Does anybody have the Azure friendly sql scripts for setting up asp.net identity? Microsoft seem to have lost them:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2006191

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if you are using:

```
User.IsInRole(...);
Roles.AddUserToRole(...);
```

and setting it up in your `web.config` using `<roleManager>`

then you're using the old-form of Identity and not the nice new Asp.net Identity 2.

Just ditch what you're doing and go for this instead:
http://johnatten.com/2014/09/21/asp-net-identity-2-0-introduction-to-working-with-identity-2-0-and-web-api-2-2/